# Scala Quill custom config location

Tags: scala, sbt, quill, typesafe-config

I'm using [Scala Quill](http://getquill.io/) library to work with database and it requires a configuration file as documented [here](http://getquill.io/#contexts-sql-contexts-mysql-quill-jdbc).

My project structure is:

```
root
|_ config
|_ project_1
|  |_ src
|     |_ main
|         |_ resources
|         |_ scala
|_ project_2
```

Now if I put my config **application.conf** in folder **resources**, everything is fine. But I want it to be in **config** instead because **project_2** also uses the file.

So how can I modify my **build.sbt** to do that?

Here is my current build.sbt:

```
val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "1.0.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.8",

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    ...
  )
)

val common = (project in file("common"))
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(name := "common")

def newProject(name: String): Project =
  Project(name, file(name))
    .settings(commonSettings)
    .settings(
      mainClass in assembly := Some(s"$name.Main"),
      assemblyJarName in assembly := s"$name.jar"
    )
    .dependsOn(common)

val project_1 = newProject("project_1")

val project_2 = newProject("project_2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share configuration between several modules, I would recommend to use standard way:

create new module which will contain shared part of config and do `project_1` and `project_2` dependent on this new module. Call common config as `reference.conf` to be loaded automatically (see [here](https://github.com/lightbend/config#standard-behavior) for details) and put in `resources` folder in new module.

Comment: I prefer to have it resides right under the root folder but still I think this is a proper way to do it.